# why change vsc highlighting color in typescript [Option 'noEmit' cannot be specified with option 'incremental']

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, tslint

I'm working on react-native. but my codes began to change color like the right

[image]

and come up the errors in **tsconfig.json**

[Error code]
`Option 'noEmit' cannot be specified with option 'incremental'.`

tsconfig error image:

[image]

I did't touch any vsc options. It is normal(first picture left) for a few seconds when I open the workspace. but after few second my code change like first picture right.

Comment: can you post your TS config file please?

Comment: Disable the setting: `Editor : Semantic Highlighting` that'll fix it for you.